# AngularJS custom filter on repeater broken

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I am trying to apply a filter on a repeater in AngularJS but am having an odd bug that is occurring.  When the page loads the repeater acts as if it is duplicating the data: 6 rows instead of 3.  Then a second later it goes to 3 rows.  When i remove the filter it works as it should with 3 rows. Here is my filter:

JS:

```
app.filter('flagged', function() {
return function(input,flag_filters) {
    var filteredElements = [];
    var filters = ["ALL"];
    if(flag_filters.length > 0)
        filters = flag_filters;
    angular.forEach(input,function(element) {
        angular.forEach(filters,function(color){
            if(angular.equals(element.flag,color) || angular.equals("ALL",color))
                filteredElements.push(element);
        });
    });
    return filteredElements;
};
```

});

View:

```
tr ng-repeat="file in files | flagged:filtered | orderBy:'date':true"
```

Data(files):
[{
   "title":"Fake Data.docx",
   "flag":"red",
   "date":"13 Sept 2013"
},{
   "title":"Fake Data.docx",
   "flag":"red",
   "date":"15 Sept 2013"
},{
   "title":"Fake Data.docx",
   "flag":"green",
   "date":"14 Sept 2013"
}]

```
filtered=["red","green"]
```

Why is it performing like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need the forEach(input,...) since the filter gets applied to each file in the repeater automatically.

Use JavaScript equality x === y and not angular.equals() unless you want to compare objects/arrays.

You should be careful of complex filters in repeaters for performance reasons.

Comment: When I use firebug through the filter, the input is always the entire array.  When I treat input as an element of the array it returns nothing. I guess I am clearly missing something on how these custom filters work.                                                      var filters = ["ALL"];
        if(flag_filters.length > 0)
            filters = flag_filters;
        if(filters.indexOf(input) !== -1)
            return input;

Comment: Nevermind the issue was with how I was making my service requests for the data.  Was actually calling it twice! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Filters on ngRepeat will pass in the entire collection as input.